# Capital gains tax and HMRC. What is the definition of a lodger and is there a difference between a friend staying a few months and a lodger?

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

I have two friends living with me and they only pay bills (no rent) and I wondering if I would be liable for CGT on the period they live there?  I don't take any rent from them at all and they are just friends staying in my house.

So, in HMRC's eyes, what is the definition of a lodger and specifically does it ever differ from a friend staying rent free in my house?

Also, in the definition of a lodger, if I let a room to a couple on one room lodger agreement does that count as one lodger or two?  (This has extremely large implications on CGT because having two lodgers makes the time they live there liable to CGT)

Comment: Answers to https://money.stackexchange.com/q/38796/3361 particularly by @martin-steeples might be helpful in determining whether bills paid by non-renters is considered taxable income in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to worry about tax if they are paying you rent.  There is no tax implication of your friends staying rent free.

Comment: And if they are paying rent, you have to worry about what happens if the outstay their welcome but don’t want to leave.

Comment: @gnasher729 I don't know about the UK, but in the districts of the US that I'm familiar with, "squatter's rights" are not changed by having ever paid a rent for the space. In some states they've even extended these rights to people who were originally trespassers into vacant spaces. In the most owner friendly districts, you'll have a minimum of 30 days after vacate notice before the authorities will even consider getting involved. What matters is a history of living there; where they "rest their head", not paying rent.

Comment: @user26460 Presumably the two friends moved in with the OP's consent, so we're not talking about squatters anyway.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this answer seems to assume that the question is about income tax, but it's actually asking about capital gains tax. For the latter, there *can* be tax implications of friends staying rent free. What actually matters is whether the OP lives in the property as well and shares living space with the friends, not whether they pay rent.

Comment: @gnasher729 Generally, lodgers (people who live in the same home and share space with their landlord) do not acquire assured shorthold tenancies in England, which means [they have far less eviction rights](https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/eviction/eviction_of_lodgers_and_other_excluded_occupiers) and, provided you haven't messed up your contract drafting, you can simply change the locks after giving a short written notice, without going to court.